# MySqli Real Escape Not Working

Tags: php, post, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

I've been using a script to upload articles to my website and done a bit of maintainance and now when I add an article on the server it's adding slashes to my text.  Here is the code that I'm using:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","db_username","db_password","db_database");

$title = ucwords($_POST['title']);
$category = $_POST['category'];
$article = $_POST['article'];
$alt = $_POST['alt'];

$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $title);
$article = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $article);
$alt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $alt);

$insert_post_sql = "INSERT INTO ".$site_id."_articles (id, category, photo, alt, title, article, added, views) VALUES('$id', '$category', '.$extension', '$alt', '$title', '$article', '$added', '$views')";
$insert_post_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_post_sql);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],"$path" . $id . "." . $extension);
header("Location: ../article.php?id=$id");
exit();
}
else{
echo "0";
};
```

So my article text looks like this: `Here\'s my article\'s text`

Can anyone tell me why escape isn't working here?

Comment: "It is not working" is not a valid error message. What *is* the error you have ?

Comment: What is the 'maintenance' you performed? Where is the query being executed?

Comment: a scientific guess: magic quotes

Comment: @YellowBird Well simply put it's adding slashes to the text when I upload it `here\'s what it\'s doing`

Comment: @RichardBernards The maintainance was mainly to the site, not the upload script so I don't really know why this is happening now when it was fine before

Comment: Everything is relevant. For example... were you using a different way to connect to your database before? Have you altered the function which saves the article? Have you installed a plugin which modifies the article before save? Etc, etc... I still cannot see any code which executes the query by the way...

Comment: @RichardBernards Evenrything is the same except the addition of `category`. I've added the code for adding to the database - The article is being added to the table, just that the slashes are not being stripped from the POST!

Comment: Add/use `stripslashes()`. The `\'` is caused by `mysqli_real_escape_string()` which is escaping the quotes.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- Done that now and all is working fine

Comment: You're welcome. It's a formula I've used for a long time.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The `\'` is NOT caused by `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, it's caused by something else.

Comment: @James I stand corrected. It's caused by not using stripslashes in conjunction with. stripslashes gets rid of the \

Comment: Yes, but using `stripslashes()` doesn't fix the root cause of the issue, the issue still occurs and `stripslashes()` removes it. The OP doesn't even know where the `/` is coming from, nor do they want it to happen, so an investigation is required to see what is happening - even if they end up using `stripslashes()`. Rather than put a bucket under a dripping tap, fix the dripping tap...

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me why escape isn't working here?

`mysqli_real_escape_string()` is possibly doing the "*escaping*" as you require, however "*is adding slashes to my text*" is not what `mysqli_real_escape_string()` does. 
Don't expect it to modify the code, or add backslashes. It just escapes chars when adding to the database.

Something other than `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is adding slashes to your text.

[mysqli_real_escape_string:](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

> Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, taking into account the current charset of the connection

.

> it's adding slashes to the text when I upload it here\'s what it\'s doing

If you have not manually coded in a script to escape with backslash, such as using the function [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php), then as @zerkms suggested, it could be you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on, which "does" escape by adding a backslash automatically.

[Determine if magic quotes are enabled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php)

If you have magic quotes enabled, read this: [Why not to use magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php)

### EDIT

The suggestion to use `stripslashes()` may well make this problem "go out of sight", but it does not fix the underlying problem, nor does it attempt to address a potential issue of you using magic quotes, again [Why not to use magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php).

Just [turn off magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php), for fixing this issue, other security concerns, and the fact it is depreciated and you shouldn't be using it in code which may not work on a newer server or from an server update.

If you have magic quotes enabled, you are now wasting resources from magic quotes adding slashes and `stripslashes()` removing them.

This is not a fix, it is a "bodge".
If you're happy with that then no worries, at all, but just FYI in my opinion this approach is not good practice at all.